# How to access Selenium driver when coding with CodeceptJs

Tags: selenium, cucumber, codeceptjs

In order to debug an issue, I'd like to try some of the raw Selenium methods such as Actions or Javascript executor to access my elements, but as I'm behind the CodeceptJs framework, I'm not sure how I'd access the driver that these methods require, please? I'm writing my tests using BDD, Cucumber and Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: Bumping this with a comment. Would love to see this presented and answered.